# Where will i get power bi sample embedded link for testing?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, powerbi

Before purchasing power bi license I want some sample embedded links for testing.  Where can I get power bi sample code with sample embedded link that is public link for testing purpose. I want to implement in my mvc web application.
I tried to google but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Embedding Power BI, along with the embed link, uses short life tokens, so obviously you can't find anything.

You can try the API and see how it works in the [playground](https://playground.powerbi.com/en-us/). Microsoft is providing examples how to embed Power BI for [your organization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/guidance/powerbi-implementation-planning-usage-scenario-embed-for-your-organization) (a.k.a. user-owns-data) and for [your customers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/guidance/powerbi-implementation-planning-usage-scenario-embed-for-your-customers) (a.k.a. app-owns-data), which you can clone and try for free with [Pro trial license](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi-pro/).